# How do I query archived tasks in Asana via their API

Tags: asana

I am interested in exporting data from Asana so we can run reports off of it.  To do this, I will need to get a list of all tasks, including those archived.  My understanding of the API that lists tasks is that if the task is archived, it will not be retrieved when getting tasks for a project.  Is there a way to query all tasks, regardless if they are archived?

Answer (score 1):

There was [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093862/archived-tasks) such question. According to [Asana API](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/) there is no such opportunity. To ask why, you should ask Asana support team.

Comment: For some reason, when I searched before I didn't see that answer.  Thank you.  I posted on here at Asana's prompting (I originally asked them).  

From their email:
"For questions about the API, please ask them on Stack Overflow. We will be monitoring the site for questions that mention Asana and answering them promptly"

Regardless, thank you for your time in helping address my question.

Answer (score 1):

Archived tasks can be accessed by including the parameter ?include_archived=true in your request for querying tasks by project.

[Task section in Asana documentation](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks)