# Asana API roadmap - getting completed tasks (including archived)

Tags: asana

Do you plan to add possibility to retrieve (via API) all tasks from project including those which are archived?

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129207/how-do-i-query-archived-tasks-in-asana-via-their-api/21492749

Answer (score 1):

(I work at Asana)

That would be a useful feature and we are already planning on adding it. However, I can't comment as to when it will be possible.

Comment: There have since been two dupes of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081582/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129207/. Any word on when this will be "possible" (lol)?

Comment: Right now we're working on a pretty important new feature for the API which will address some really big functionality and scalability concerns for our developers. After that, we will likely be looking at how to make data retrieval / search more powerful. Unfortunately, I can't promise anything on the timeline here.

Comment: When will this pretty important new feature be rolling out?

Comment: We're finishing up the design phase; since we haven't even started implementation, it's difficult to tell, probably a couple of months. We don't have the bandwidth at the moment to do more than that plus a few little API improvements here or there. If you want us to work faster, we're hiring--refer us someone good to help out! :)

Comment: I'm joining fellow developers, this feature will be great to have! Please update us on when we can expect it...

Answer (score 1):

Archived tasks can be accessed by including the parameter ?include_archived=true in your request for querying tasks by project.

[Task section in Asana documentation](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks)

Answer (score 1):

Until the API officially supports this, you can always query `/tasks?completed_since=now` to get only incomplete tasks, then query `/tasks`, and filter for tasks that only appear in the second list.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do this exact same thing as well.  We are using a project to track line down events on our manufacturing floor.  I found this post helpful and you can append “?include_archived=true” to your query but I found out that you can also do a reverse lookup on tasks by their tag.  This will also show achieved tasks as well.