# Get archived tasks from asana

Tags: asana

We are trying to get the tasks from Asana using the Asana API to create a customized dashboard. But we couldn't get archived tasks using the API.
Is there anyway to get all tasks including the archived tasks using the API?
If this feature doesn't exist will it be added in the upcoming releases?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually a flag, `include_archived` that you can set to `true`, which will cause a query for tasks to (you guessed it!) include the archived tasks as well. See https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks for more details (esp. the "Querying for Tasks" section).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this with my script. I added '&include_archived=true' to my url, but, its only returning the tasks which are non archived.

Comment: @user2109788 Can you specify the exact URL (you can replace IDs with ### or something), just so I can try to reproduce?

Comment: Sorry! the url was wrong, checked it again and corrected it. It works fine. Thanks for the help..